# why receiving 2 letters when using telnet?

Tags: netty

I am looking this page:http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html
[image]

when I use 'telnet 127.0.0.1 8080' and send some letters:
[image]

why..?

Answer (score 1):

Because it first "prints" what you entered there and then also what is echoed back.

This should give you a better idea:

`echo "test" | nc 127.0.0.1 8080`

Comment: when I remove the code line (1) and (2), restart the server. type some letter. It don't show any letter in cmd.